# No function $f$ with $\hat{f}=(-1)^k/\sqrt{k}$ exists for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}, k \neq0$

Tags: fourier-series

I just started learning about the Fourier series, is this statement true or false?

Looking at $\mathcal {R}(-\pi,\pi)$. No function $f$ with $\hat{f}=(-1)^k/\sqrt{k}$ exists for all  $k\in\mathbb{Z}, k \neq0$.

Comment: Interesting that you mention $\sqrt{k}$ even when $k<0$.  Am I right that $\mathcal R$ is "Riemann integrable"?

Comment: $\mathcal {R}$ means real numbers, oh so this just means that the statement is wrong right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If
$$
\sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} a_k e^{i k t}
$$
is the Fourier series of a square-integrable Lebesgue measurable function $f$ on $[-\pi,\pi)$, then [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) states
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f(t)|^2\;dt = \sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} |a_k|^2
$$
Now a Riemann integrable function on $[\pi,\pi]$ is bounded and Lebesgue measurable, so
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f(t)|^2\;dt < +\infty
$$
But on the other hand, if $a_k = (-1)^k/\sqrt{k}$ for $k=1,2,3\dots$, then
$$
\sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} |a_k|^2 \ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} = +\infty .
$$

---

On the other hand, what if $f$ is not square integrable?  Maple suggests
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}} e^{ikt} =
\operatorname{Li}_{1/2}(-e^{it})
$$
where $\operatorname{Li}_{1/2}$ is a [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) .  Of course
the convergence is only conditional.  Here is the graph
[image: graph]
Real part in blue, imaginary part in red.